# Setup SSL with vapor

Tags: swift, ubuntu, ssl, lets-encrypt, vapor

I have a config like this

```
{
    "default": {
        "port": "443",
        "host": "example.com",
        "securityLayer": "tls",
        "tls": {
            "certificates": "files",
            "certificateFile": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem",
            "privateKeyFile": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"
        }
    }
}
```

On `drop` startup it prints out this console message:

```
No TLS signature supplied, defaulting to selfSigned.
```

Judging by the code that produces that error message it expects `signature` field in the config that would be either `selfSigned`, `signedFile` or `signedDirectory`

[image]

I have this files from `let's encrypt`:

- cert.pem
- chain.pem
- fullchain.pem
- privkey.pem

What do I do to resolve that error message?

Comment: Is the default `selfSigned` causing any issues?

Comment: @tanner0101 looks like its working, but you tell me if that's normal :)

Comment: @tanner0101 I see the warning message and assume I need to resolve it. If that's normal, that warning probably should be removed from `Droplet+TLS.swift`.

Comment: If it's working, then just add `signature: selfSigned` to your servers.json

Comment: @tanner0101 Ok. Am I missing out on something by not using `cert.pem` and `chain.pem`?

Comment: `signature: selfSigned` does make the warning go away.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix problem

```
{
    "default": {
        "port": "443",
        "host": "example.com",
        "securityLayer": "tls",
        "tls": {
            "signature": "signedFile",
            "certificates": "files",
            "certificateFile": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem",
            "privateKeyFile": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"
        }
    }
}
```

---

Vapor don't recommend to use SSL cert directly in Vapor.

You should consider use ngix or apache as SSL-proxy: https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/deploy/nginx/